# How to make old hard drive non bootable

Tags: windows, bootloader, boot-camp, diskpart

My system's dual booting MacOS and Windows using Boot Camp. I have an external hard drive that came from an old computer, and sometimes when I try to boot to Windows with the drive attached, the system tries trying to boot from it. However I've deleted the old files from the disc. Old EFI partition is still present. I've tried `diskpart inactive`, and all I get from every partition is

```
The disk is not a fixed MBR disk.
The INACTIVE command can only be used on fixed MBR disks.
```

Comment: Welcome to the community. Unfortunately this is a bit unclear... you've tagged this with 'boot-camp' - how is that related to the issue? What exactly is the OS? Have you tried simply deleting all partitions from the external drive, creating a new partition and formatting it? Have you tried changing the boot order in the BIOS so that the internal drive is first? Please edit your question to add new info / clarifications instead of answering in a comment so that all the relevant info is readily available.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I have both macos and windows setup on my computer, and sometimes while booting into windows my second drive will try to boot up

Comment: The disk might have an EFI partition that confuses the BIOS. Use Disk Management (or macOS) to delete it. If it's not clearly identified as EFI, you may find it by its size of typically 500 MB. Ensure you're deleting from the right disk.

Comment: yep ur right there is one there, is it definetely safe to delete as the drive has tons of data on it

Comment: Yes, deleting this one small partition shouldn't affect the rest, but be careful.

Comment: I edited the question adding the new info you provided, please verify and correct any mistakes.. SE communities aren't discussion boards, so they work a bit differently. I'd suggest you read through the Asking- and Answering -sections in https://superuser.com/help. That'll give you helpful information on how to ask well-formatted, clear questions that are easier to answer, and how to write good answers.